# How to "setup" screen using a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-screen

I'm trying to write a bash script to create a screen (software) session with a specific set of windows, and `cd` to specific directories on each one.

Here is the script I have so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

killall screen;
screen -AmdS work;
screen -S work bash -c "cd myDir";
```

The problem is that I can't seem to change directories on that session. After running this script, I run `$ screen -r` and the current directory is still my default directory (~/).

(I've tried changing the `cd` command to `touch myFile` and the file is there after I run the script)

Comment: If you try `bash -c "cd myDir"` in your terminal, you'll see that it doesn't change directories. Use the screen command (**not** shell command) `chdir` to change directories, then open a new shell and it will start in that directory

Comment: Well -- it changes directories, but it changes the directory *of the new shell you started with the `bash` command*, not the directory of the shell/program that ran it. And since that new shell is exiting as soon as it finishes running the script it was passed with `bash -c`...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try the following, it will open a new screen session with a bash which will change the directory and open a new bash with this directory as current:

```
screen -S work bash -c 'cd myDir && exec bash'
```

Adding `-d -m` to run it in detached mode. And after reattaching you will be in `myDir`:

```
screen -S work -d -m bash -c 'cd myDir && exec bash'
```

**Better solution**

The following code will create a detached screen with 3 screens each running `myCommand1/2/3` in directory `myDir1/2/3`.

```
cd myDir1
screen -S work -d -m
screen -S work -X exec myCommand1
screen -S work -X chdir myDir2
screen -S work -X screen
screen -S work -X exec myCommand2
screen -S work -X chdir myDir3
screen -S work -X screen
screen -S work -X exec myCommand3
cd -
```

Note the last `cd -` that will return you back to your original working directory.

Finally just use `screen -r work` to attach your running screen session.

Comment: `cd mydir && exec bash` avoids leaving the parent process sitting in memory

Comment: @CharlesDuffy even better, thanks.. i'll update the answer with `exec`

Answer (score 2):

You can save the command line you want to run (including the final newline) into a register and paste it into the screen input:

```
screen -S work -X register c $'cd myDir\n'
screen -S work -X paste c
```